# angular2 - skip first item in ngFor

Tags: javascript, loops, angular

I want to skip the first item with `ngFor`:

```
<li *ngFor="#m +1 of [1,2,3,4]">{{m}}</li>
```

the output should be: **2,3,4**

What is the best way to do this in Angular2?

Comment: What should it do? What is in `test`? Should it skip the first item?

Comment: yes, it should skip the first item

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can start with the second (or any arbitrary offset) items of the collection with the help of [slice pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html):

```
<div *ngFor="#m of [1,2,3] | slice:1">{{ m }}</div> // will print 2 and 3
```