# splice element from ngFor angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm requesting a list of locations from the back-end and using it in `ngFor` however I want to remove the first array element.

Say I want to remove `Id:0` so it won't so in my `li` element. Here's an array of list that I'm rendering and wanted to remove `StoreHouse`

```
 [
  {
    'Id': 0,
    'StoreLocation': 'StoreHouse'
  },
  {
    'Id': 1,
    'StoreLocation': 'Eastleigh'
  },
  {
    'Id': 2,
    'StoreLocation': 'Portchester'
  },
  {
    'Id': 3,
    'StoreLocation': 'Soho'
  },
  {
    'Id': 4,
    'StoreLocation': 'Basingstoke'
  }
];
```

Is there a way to not render `Id:0` in `li` when doing `ngFor`?

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjZtql97kU8rMVosFhOj?p=preview)

Comment: You want just to miss this element in loop ?

Comment: Duplicate. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405374/angular2-ngfor-skip-first-index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 - skip first item in ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265441/angular2-skip-first-item-in-ngfor)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html):

```
<li *ngFor="#data of lengthArray | slice:1">
  //content 
</li>
```

Comment: Yeah saw the duplicate question with `slice:1` pipe. Thanks

Comment: You should not answer a duplicate. You have privilege. You should mark it as duplicate