# *ngFor to print only the first element of an array

Tags: html, angular

i'm using this code:

```
   <div *ngIf="gamedata.notOver" class="columns">
                <div class="column has-text-centered" *ngFor="let board of boards; let i = index">
                    <table class="is-bordered" [style.opacity]="i == player ? 0.5 : 1">
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of board.tiles; let j = index">
                            <td *ngFor="let col of row; let k = index" (click)="boardListener($event)" [style.background-color]="col.used ? '' : 'transparent'" [class.win]="col.status == 'win'" [class.fail]="col.status !== 'win'" class="battleship-tile" id="t{{i}}{{j}}{{k}}">
                                {{ col.value == "1" ? (col.status == "hit" ? "" : "X") : (col.status == "miss" ? "⛶" : (col.status == "hit" ? "" : "")) }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr>
                </div>
   </div>
```

to print the first element of an array of arrays that contains 2 elements, how can i choose to print the first or the second element without printing both of them? i need to do this since i have to put both of them in separate divs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splice element from ngFor angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716668/splice-element-from-ngfor-angular2)

Comment: (Don't code a game in angular since this framework se a virtual DOM).

Comment: If you have only two items, why not separate it and don't treat it as an array ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi out of context, you can code several games with Angular, as long as they're not the size of Skyrim ...

Comment: Out of context? for real? There are tons of reasons to not use jQuery directly with angular, and same goes for canvas and other native element.

Comment: Why not code an interface and game state in Angular. And if it's graphical game, use a specific library for handling the rest in embedded canvas? What's wrong with this approach? Sorry for off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the line that refers to the array of arrays is the board of boards one.

Try wrapping each array in an ng-content that has an ngIf directive as follows:

```
<div class="column has-text-centered" *ngFor="let board of boards; let i = index">
    <ng-content *ngIf="i%2 == 0">
        INSERT WHAT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY FOR FIRST ARRAY ITEM HERE
    </ng-content>
    <ng-content *ngIf="i%2 != 0">
        INSERT WHAT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY FOR SECOND ARRAY ITEM HERE
    </ng-content>
</div>
```

You may have to repeat some code, but it should work.